# Print on new tab 'about:blank' and close after printed like datatable lib

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I like the way datatable does the printing, by clicking the PRINT button, new window opens (not in popup window), than the print prompt appears, after you click PRINT or CANCEL the opened tab closes!
I want to modify, or to be honest, I want to create my own customized script code!
So all i did till now is that i found out how to open a new about:blank page:

```
<a href="about:blank" target="_blank">PRINT</a>
```

So how to populate it inside of blank page with a table with data, and how to close that page automatically after finishing printing? What is the JavaScript behind it?

Like this example: https://jsfiddle.net/ms85e7zo/

Notice! I don't want to use datatable library for this, I want just a clear concept how it is possible to do that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check the [source](https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.print.js) of the DataTables print button you can see the logic which achieves the effect you're after. Note that `win` is a reference to the popup which was created and had the content injected in to.

```js
var autoPrint = function() {
  if (config.autoPrint) {
    win.print(); // blocking - so close will not
    win.close(); // execute until this is done
  }
};

if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident\/\d.\d/)) { // IE needs to call this without a setTimeout
  autoPrint();
} else {
  win.setTimeout(autoPrint, 1000);
}
```

In short, all they do is call `print()`, which blocks the main browser thread, and then immediately afterwards call `close()`. As a result, no matter if the user decided to go ahead with the print or cancel it, as soon as execution resumes after the modal is dismissed the new window is closed. The `setTimeout()` is only to ensure that all styles and data has been loaded in IE before printing.

It's a simple and effective solution.

Comment: config.autoPrint undefined, I set it always true, then it's work~